# nginx error:"location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76

Tags: nginx

When i restart the nginx with, sudo service nginx restart,

Iam facing with this error,

Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {


    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


        location / {
        /home/techcee/scrapbook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc/
       }
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# `enter code here`
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

What is wrong in this ?

Answer (score 51):

"location" directive should be inside a 'server' directive, e.g.

```
server {
    listen       8765;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: and where should the server directive be ???

Comment: @Matt Inside the `http` directive. Really you should not be editing `nginx.conf`, but instead creating a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` with your `server` directive.

Comment: ...unless directive is in another conf file and you include it with an include directive.

Answer (score 27):

The **server** directive has to be in the **http directive**. It should not be outside of it.

Incase if you need detailed information, refer [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server).

Comment: The question is about the 'location' directive.

Comment: ...And the link is broken

Answer (score 11):

Since your server already includes the `sites-enabled` folder ( *notice the `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` line* ), then you better use that.

1. Create a file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and call it whatever you want, I'll call it `django` since it's a djanog server

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/django
   ```
2. Then create a symlink that points to it

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/django /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
   ```
3. Then edit that file with whatever file editor you use, `vim` or `nano` or whatever and create the server inside it

   ```
   server {
       # hostname or ip or multiple separated by spaces
       server_name localhost example.com 192.168.1.1; #change to your setting
       location / {
           root /home/techcee/scrapbook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc/;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Restart or reload nginx settings

   ```
   sudo service nginx reload
   ```

**Note** I believe that your configuration like this probably won't work yet because you need to pass it to a fastcgi server or something, but at least this is how you could create a *valid* server

Comment: ok I just read about gunicorn, are you using a port number or a sockfile in gunicorn ?

Comment: Iam using port number

Answer (score 6):

The *location* directive should be in the s*e*rver directive, which in turn should be in the *http* directive. See example below for a reverse proxy:

```
http {
    server {
        location /some-path {
            proxy_pass             http://1.2.3.4;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is adapted from the [Wiki example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/). More examples and documentation on the site.

By the way, be aware of the effect of `include` directives.