# How to block sites on an nginx server by 403

Tags: nginx

I've searched quite a while now and I'm out of ideas. Recently I've set up my first own webserver on nginx to host a wordpress website. Now I wanted to block the admin areas by a 403 to everyone outside my home network. I've tried 5 different metheods, but none did work.

1. Through [sites-available/default](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2016/11/hosting-wordpress-on-raspberry-pi-part-2-install-nginx-php-and-mariadb/)
2. Through the [nginx.conf](http://www.linuxfunda.com/2013/09/01/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-url-in-ngnix/)
3. Through [sites-available/django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392741/nginx-errorlocation-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-etc-nginx-nginx-conf76)
4. A second time through [nginx.conf](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-block-url-access-all-except-one-ip-address/)
5. And a last time through [sites-enabled](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/how-to-deny-directory-by-ip-address-in-nginx.48487/)

That's my **nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 16m;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_types
            application/atom+xml
           application/javascript
           application/json
           application/rss+xml
           application/vnd.ms-fontobject
           application/x-font-ttf
           application/x-web-app-manifest+json
           application/xhtml+xml
           application/xml
           font/opentype
           image/svg+xml
           image/x-icon
           text/css
           text/plain
           text/x-component;

    ##
    # Cache Settings
    ##

    add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;



    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**That's my sites-available/default**

```
# Default server configuration
#
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:10m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|/index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commeters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }



    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;


            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}

}



# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80; 
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|/index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commeters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;


            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}



    # Only allow access of /admin and wp-admin via internal IP
    location ~ /admin/.*\.php$ {
       allow 192.168.0.0/24;
       deny all;
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `server` blocks in your *default* file. The second block seems superfluous and will never be selected.

The regular expression `location` that has been added to the end of one `server` block, **will never be selected**. Regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order.

```
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
location ~ /admin/.*\.php$ { ... }
```

Any URI that matches the second regular expression will have already matched the first.

You need to reverse the order of the `location` blocks for your scheme to have any chance of working. Of course, you also need to place it in the correct `server` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I didn't thought about the order, but the thing I would never tried, was putting the command into the second server block, which is labeled "Virtual Host configuration" and where most things are commented out. But exactly there is there place, where I had to put it.